# Trying to Pull Request on git hub but

Tags: github, repository

I tried to PR my script but it did not work. After I did git commit -m then git push, I got this error:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix it? thankyou

Comment: Looks like you might not have the push access to the repository. Check with the admin of the repo to provide you push access.

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote URL:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

Its URL might still reference the origina repository instead [of your fork](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).

If that is the case, change the URL with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/<myFork>
```